# How to add items to TListView with DynamicAppearance?

Tags: listview, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.1-berlin

How can I add items to DynamicAppearance Listview in runtime? On design mode I created the layout of ListView which I want. I added 3 TTextObjectAppearance. How can I set those 3 TTextObjectAppearance text dynamically?

Comment: Got it working:
var
  list : TListViewItem;
  ldes, lOrder, lLegal : TListItemText;
begin
  list := ListView1.Items.Add;
  ldes := list.Objects.FindObjectT<TListItemText>('Description');
  lOrder := list.Objects.FindObjectT<TListItemText>('OrderId');
  lLegal := list.Objects.FindObjectT<TListItemText>('LegalCode');
  ldes.Text := 'Mouri';
  lOrder.Text := 'Love';
  lLegal.Text := 'You'
end;

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Congratulations on solving your problem. Please add your solution in the *answer* section below so that it's clear to future visitors that this problem is solved. Comments here should be regarded as ephemeral.

Answer (score 8):

I took the time to format the answer that was posted in the original question's comments by the original poster.

```
var list : TListViewItem; 
    ldes, lOrder, lLegal : TListItemText; 
begin 
   list := ListView1.Items.Add; 
   ldes := list.Objects.FindObjectT<TListItemText>('Description'); 
   lOrder := list.Objects.FindObjectT<TListItemText>('OrderId'); 
   lLegal := list.Objects.FindObjectT<TListItemText>('LegalCode'); 
   ldes.Text := 'Mouri'; 
   lOrder.Text := 'Love'; 
   lLegal.Text := 'You' 
end;
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way to change the text would be:

```
for i := 0 to Listview1.Itemcount-1 do begin

  Listview1.Items.AppearanceItem[i].Data['Description'] := 'Mouri';
  Listview1.Items.AppearanceItem[i].Data['OrderID'] := 'loves';
  Listview1.Items.AppearanceItem[i].Data['LegalCode'] := 'YOU!';

end;
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the answer wasn't working for me to change the text color of a TTextObjectAppearance item. What I did, on a bound/design-made (dynamicAppeareance) Listview is the following:

```
procedure TReportsForm.lvwReportsUpdateObjects(const Sender: TObject;
  const AItem: TListViewItem);

var drw: TListItemDrawable;
    cpt: string;

begin
    drw:=AItem.Objects.FindDrawable('Concept');
    if (drw <> nil) then begin
        cpt := AItem.Data['Concept'].AsString;
        if (cpt = 'BAD') then
          (drw as TListItemText).TextColor := TAlphaColorRec.Indianred
        else
          (drw as TListItemText).TextColor := TAlphaColorRec.Cadetblue
    end;
end;
```